# Latex-free first aid kit

Tags: hiking, scotland

I plan to go on a hike with someone allergic to latex.

Usually I would pack small plasters and leukotape, but this is not an option in this case.

How can I replace these items with latex-free equivalents in the UK?

Comment: Dialect Note: BrEng "plasters" is approximately the same as AmEng "Band-aids" or "bandages" (and for the OP's benefit, in AmEng "plasters" are substances used to patch holes in walls).    That said, are there not nitrile gloves and fabric bandages available in your area?

Comment: Latex free plasters will be stocked by most pharmacies. [Bandaid](https://www.band-aid.com/search/site/latex%20free) have them. Elastoplast have "sensitive skin" ones, but these may not be latex free.

Comment: Aren't there many options? There is even spray-on plaster/band-aid that just makes a film. Some small rolls of cotton gauze?

Comment: You can certainly buy latex free plasters in bigger chemists' in the UK and nitrile or even vinyl gloves. Pre-packed first aid kits often include nitrile rather than latex gloves (unless they're very cheap) but it's not always stated

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone! I will follow up on the comments and report :)

Comment: I did find some st john latex-free plasters - nothing like a roll of leukotape yet.

Comment: Would micropore tape work for you?

Answer (score 1):

In short, all items containing latex in most first aid kits can be replaced by latex free products, a well stocked chemist or drugstore. And with a bit of preparation time they can order what is not in the shop.

For plasters you have found an alternative from St John, you mentioned in a comment, there are (other) brands found in an online search, so you have the choice of several.
For sticky tape I found several looking for 'latex free medical tape', I guess you will find more if you also search on sports tape and plasters (as that gave good results in a Dutch search.)

As indicated in the comments, latex free gloves are almost standard in the more expensive kits, even when not stated, but buying a box of them should be not too hard.

And think a bit out of the box, if medical sticky tape is hard to find, you can often also use a 'wind around the hand/arm/leg bandage' which you fix with an 'on the bandage' set of hooks on elastic. Or even with a bit of non medical tape if it is acceptable for this person.